# RACCommand compilation failure on swift 1.2

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, reactive-cocoa

I have a login button with a RACCommand assigned to it to perform a login request and return me a user object.

I want to handle the errors from the buttons signal errors.

```
loginButton.rac_command.executionSignals.flatten()
            .logAll()
            .subscribeNext { (_:AnyObject!) -> Void in
                    println("Sent next")
            }
```

so i added the doError block before the subscribeNext block but now the code doesn't compile:

```
    loginButton.rac_command.executionSignals.flatten()
        .logAll()
        .doError { (err:NSError) -> Void in
            println(err.description)
        }
        .subscribeNext { (_:AnyObject!) -> Void in
                println("Sent next")
        }
```

Now it comes back with the error:

```
cannot invoke 'subscribeNext' with an argument list of type '(AnyObject! -> Void)'
```

Since the signature of doError is :

```
- (RACSignal *)doError:(void (^)(NSError *error))block;
```

I'm assuming that its giving me back the same signal that was passed to the doError block so i can subscribeNext to it.

Not sure why this fails to compile at all though.
Any insight to this issue is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo is in argument of `doError()` (and incorrectly identified by compiler): it should be of type `(NSError!) -> Void` instead of `(NSError) -> Void`. Modified like this it compiles fine:

```
loginButton.rac_command.executionSignals.flatten()
    .logAll()
    .doError { (err:NSError!) -> Void in
        println(err.description)
    }
    .subscribeNext { (_:AnyObject!) -> Void in
            println("Sent next")
    }
```

**Additional remarks**

- Errors from `RACCommand` are caught internally and sent on `errors()`
  signal, so none are sent on `executionSignals()` signal.
- `doNext()`, `doError()`, `doComplete()` methods are to be used for
  injecting side effects to the signal. So you typically use them while
  creating signal, not when handling its events. You might want to use
  `subscribeNext(nextBlock:error:completed:)` method (or one of its convenience forms) instead.